Expressing the Axiom of Pairing as a fragment of Unrestricted Comprehension
I would like to rewrite the Axiom of Pairing as a fragment of the Unrestricted Comprehension Schema, but without the use of Russell-like or Curry-like paradoxes ($\exists\{x:\neg\text{"axiom of pairing"}\rightarrow x\notin x\}$ would force axiom of pairing for example).
How could this be done?
I have come up so far with the following schema. I imagine that it "works" as follows: if $a$ and $b$ are extensions of $\varphi$ and $\psi$ and they exist, then there exists a set containing both of them.
$\exists y\forall x(x\in y \leftrightarrow [\exists a,b([\forall x(x\in a \leftrightarrow \varphi(x))]\land[\forall x(x\in b\leftrightarrow \psi(x))]\land[(x=a)\lor(x=b)])])$
I suppose that one problem is that the schema above is sort of restricted only to those elements $a,b$ that are extensions of some expressible properties ($\varphi, \psi$).
Second problem could be that the schema above forces at least one element to exist, but the axiom of pairing does no such thing.
Is there a better way to do this? Does the schema above work at least for these expressible elements? Thanks.

Not very clear... What is wrong with the usual form: $\forall a,b \exists x \forall y [y \in x \leftrightarrow (y=a \lor y=b)]$? Use formula $\varphi(y)= (y=a \lor y=b)$ with Unrestricted Comprehension: $\exists x \forall y [y \in x \leftrightarrow \varphi(y)]$

@MauroALLEGRANZA oh, I did not fully realize that instances of Unrestricted Comprehension can also be formulas and not just sentences. Then I would just use universal generalization on such formula and get the Axiom of Pairing, correct? thanks

Pairs axiom: $∀a,b∃x∀y[y∈x ↔ (y=a ∨ y=b)]$, is a conditional axiom: it does not force at least one element to exist. It asserts the existence of the pair set for every couple of existing sets.
And yes, it can be considered an instance of Unrestricted Comprehension: $∃x∀y[y∈x ↔ φ(y)]$ where formula $φ$ is $(y=a ∨ y=b)$.
We need it in $\mathsf {ZFC}$ exactly because Unrestricted Comprehension is not available.
